# Trace of a bilinear form?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, bilinear-form

I'm just a beginner of differential geometry, so please forgive me if this is nothing but a silly question or I'm making a critical conceptual mistake.

Let $\mathrm{I\!I}(X, Y)$ be the second fundamental form on an embedded $n$-manifold in the $(n+1)$-dimensional Euclidean space. Then the mean curvature $H$ is defined as the trace of $\mathrm{I\!I}( \cdot, \cdot)$ divided by $n$. But my question arises here. What does the trace of a bilinear form means, especially in the sense of a tensor field on a coordinate chart? Of course, considering $\mathrm{I\!I}(\xi^i g_i, \eta^j g_j) = \mathrm{I\!I}(g_i, g_j) \xi^i \eta_j$ gives us a matrix representation $h_{ij} = \mathrm{I\!I}(g_i, g_j)$ with respect to the contravariant basis. But if we take $H$ as a mere trace of this matrix $(h_{ij})$, we only have a quantity that is not invariant under the change of coordinate, which seems obviously undesirable. I know that I have trouble understanding the nature of $\mathrm{I\!I}( \cdot, \cdot)$, since the correct answer would be $(1/n)h_{i}^{i}$, where $h_{i}^{j} = h_{il}g^{lj}$. Is there any generous soul who can help me out from this conceptual messup?

Comment: You are aware that you can simply compute the mean curvature locally as $H = g^{ij}h_{ij}$, and this is of course invariant?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a purely local issue. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real inner product space with inner product $\langle -, - \rangle$. Then endomorphisms $T : V \to V$ can be naturally identified with bilinear forms on $V$ via the identification $T \mapsto \langle -, T(-) \rangle$. The inverse identification exists thanks to the "Riesz representation theorem" (trivial in this setting). In particular, the trace of a bilinear form can be identified with the trace of the corresponding endomorphism, and so is well-defined up to *orthogonal* change of coordinates.

Another way of saying this is as follows. You are correct that bilinear forms $V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ don't have a well-defined notion of trace for $V$ only a real vector space; what has a well-defined notion of trace is an endomorphism $V \to V$, and this is because we can identify endomorphisms with elements of $V \otimes V^{\ast}$, and the dual pairing gives a distinguished map $V \otimes V^{\ast} \to \mathbb{R}$. Because one does not need to make any choices to define this map, it is automatically invariant under change of coordinates.

Bilinear forms, on the other hand, are elements of $V^{\ast} \otimes V^{\ast}$, and no analogue of the dual pairing exists here in general. However, if $V$ is an inner product space, the inner product gives a distinguished isomorphism $V \simeq V^{\ast}$ sending $v \in V$ to $\langle -, v \rangle$ and then the identification above is possible.

Comment: You gave the linear algebra reason. Geometrically, an orthogonal change of (local) coordinates is (by definition) a local isometry, hence it should not change geometric quantities such as curvature (indeed geometrically meaningful quantities *should be* invariant under local isometries). On the other hand, if you allow non-orthogonal changes you might end up scaling some directions, hence you should also expect change of curvature in general.

Comment: Thanks! This identification clearly yields the 'correct' representation of $\mathrm{I\! I}$ for calculating the trace, namely $(h_{i}^{j})$.

Comment: @sos440: yes, as long as you compute everything using an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}
\def\bil{\operatorname{Bil}}$Just for the sake of completeness, I will write here how to compute the trace of a bilinear form explicitly under Qiaochu Yuan's definition. Let $V$ be a real finite-dimensional inner product space. If $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis on $V$, then the trace of a bilinear form $b$ on $V$ can be computed as
$$
\tr b=\sum_ib(e_i,e_i).
$$
*Proof.* We want to determine the associated endomorphism $T:V\to V$ to $b$. We know that it must satisfy $b(-,-)=\langle T(-),-\rangle$. Denote $\rho_{ij}$ to be the endomorphism of $V$ such that $\rho_{ij}e_k=\delta_{ik}e_j$ (we are using Einstein summation convention). Then $\{\rho_{ij}\}$ is a basis of the space of endomorphisms on $V$. Write $T=T^{ij}\rho_{ij}$. We want to determine $T^{ij}$. Note that $T^{ij}=e^j(Te_i)$, where $\{e^j\}\subset V^*$ is the dual basis of $\{e_j\}$. It is easy to verify that $e^j=\langle -,e_j\rangle$. Hence, $T^{ij}=\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle=b(e_i,e_j)$. Thus, the trace of the endomorphism $T=T^{ij}\rho_{ij}=\sum_{ij}b(e_i,e_j)\rho_{ij}$ is $\tr b=\sum_i b(e_i,e_i)$. $\square$

---

More generally, if $W$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space, one can define the trace of a bilinear map $b:V\times V\to W$ in the following way: There is a natural isomorphism $\Phi:V\otimes V^*\otimes W\cong\bil(V,V;W)$ that sends the tensor $u\otimes\eta\otimes w$ to the bilinear map $(v_1,v_2)\mapsto u^\flat(v_1)\eta(v_2)w$.

Hence, we define the *trace* of a bilinear map $b:V\times V\to W$ to be the image of $\Phi^{-1}(b)$ under the evaluation map
\begin{align*}
    V\otimes V^*\otimes W&\to W\\
    u\otimes\eta\otimes w&\mapsto\eta(u)w.
\end{align*}

Using a similar proof idea as above, one can verify that if $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$, then $\tr b=\sum_ib(e_i,e_i)$. In particular, considering $W=k$ recovers the other case.